# Find longest Valid Parentheses(leetcode)

Tags: c++, char

eg: if a string is `")(((())))))("`, the answer should be 8.
I implement as follow:(learn from others)

```
int longestValidParentheses(string s) {
    int len = s.length();
    char* str = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(str,s.c_str());
    int maxlen=0;
    stack<char*> stk;
    char* cur = str;
    while(*cur)
    {
        if(*cur=='(')
            stk.push(cur);
        else
        {
            if(!stk.empty() && *stk.top()=='(')
            {
                stk.pop();
                maxlen = max(maxlen, cur-(stk.empty()?str-1:stk.top()));
            }
            else
                stk.push(cur);
        }
        cur++;
    }
    return maxlen;
}
```

but I don't know why for this code, `char* str = new char[len+1]` but not `char* str = new char[len]`. Could anybody tell me why? If I use `char* str = new char[len]`, an error will occur.

Comment: There is a terminating `'\0'` at the end of a string that you need to make space for.

Comment: The problem statement isn't 100% clear. What should the answer be for `"(()())"`? If it's `2` (i.e., you're looking for the longest run of N characters consisting of N/2 `(` followed by N/2 `)`), then I don't think you need a stack, just a count of consecutive `(` and another count of consecutive `)`, plus another count for the maximum seen so far.

Comment: "... an error will occur" -- **what** error?

Comment: It works fine on my VS, but not passed in leetcode online judge, I do not know the what exactly error is, it shows run-time error only for text case:")(((())))))(". The answer for "(()())" should be 6 not 2. i.e.if it is "()(()", answer should be 2. I think @Floris has answered my question, but why using strcpy is a bad idea? BTW, Thanks for help edit my question.

Comment: If you want me to see a comment, you need to mention my user name preceded by an `@` sign. Click the "help" link next to the comment entry box for more information. The problem statement still isn't 100% clear. Is there a problem definition you can link to? (Don't assume everyone knows what "leetcode" is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can tell from the comments, your problem is in the fact that you are mixing some constructs that are really `C++` (like the `string` type) with functions and data types that are more typical of C (like `char*`, `strcpy`, etc). Bottom line: the length of a string is the number of characters in it; but the storage space needed is bigger than that, because a `char*` type of string has a terminating `'\0'` character to indicate "end of string". If you don't allocate space for that, then the `'\0'` that is appended at the end of the string copy operation will overwrite another memory location with possibly disastrous consequences.

Comment: I see...So that's why I need to allocate len+1 instead len, but I think while(*cur) works equal as while(*cur!='\0'), am i right?

Comment: You are right - when `*cur==\0` , `if(*cur)` will go to the `else` part since zero is converted to `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

You have no need to make a copy of the string in order to iterate it, since `string` comes with perfectly nice iterators that work *exactly* like `char*`:

The first 10 or so lines can be replaced by:

```
int maxlen = 0;
auto cur = s.begin(), end = s.end();
std::stack<decltype(cur)> stk;
while (cur != end) {
```

If you don't have C++11, use

```
std::string::iterator
```

in place of `auto` and `decltype(cur)`.

One can also use indexes, or even make a `char*` into the string's own content:

```
cur = &s[0];
```

In no case is making a copy of the string and then leaking it a good idea.

Comment: Your way works much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Floris already had given you the answer for your question. Let me just add one thing: you did not have to make a copy of that string. Note that you are allocating a buffer (new [len+1]) and you are strcpy'ing into it a value that you've got from `s.c_str()`.

Check what is the c_str! The thing you are copying into your buffer is just an array of chars, `char*`, that you can completely appropriately use just like your new buffer. Try it:

```
int len = s.length();
char const* str = s.c_str();
```

and it should work just the same, without having to make a copy. **(maybe you'll need to add some consts in a few places)**

Comment: I tried your way at first second, but it will not work when I push current char* to my stack, since it is constant

Comment: @DoReMi: use `std::stack<char const*>`

Answer (score 0):

```
int longestValidParentheses(string s){
    int pos = 0;
    int maxlen = 0;
    while(pos != -1){
           pos = substr(pos).find("(");
           if(str.substr(pos).find(")") == -1) pos = -1;
           maxlen += 2;
           pos++;
    }
    return maxlen;
}
```

If you're using C++ might as well use the tools you have been given.

Comment: If so, time complexity will be increased